# Images Not Showing In Civicrm Contact Dashboard

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home

Uploaded image not displaying in the contact dashboard even though the uploaded images is in the correct folderand the image url is properly set in Civicrm.  Pease whatcould be the problem.
Using Civicrm 4.6.2 with current drupal 7

Comment: We'd love to help you - but we'll need more information to help!  Could you please open your Developer tools (F12 in Firefox/Chrome, go to the "Net" tab, and look for errors (especially 404 errors) on the Net tab?  Please update the question with the URLs that have errors, along with the error message.